# Utility function for a combination of a normal good and necessary good

Tags: utility, consumer-theory

I am trying to formulate a decision problem for an agent involving their heating-energy consumption $c$. Let $x$ denote all other consumption. What would be a reasonable utility function to employ here? I want to capture the intuition that heating energy is a necessary good, whereas everything else might be modelled as a normal good.

Something like Cobb-Douglas doesn't work since $x$ and $c$ would then both be normal goods. Is CES utility an option? Would be grateful for any references that consider similar setups.

Comment: Hi! Do you know what a homothetic function is? Also, have you studied microeconomics? I am guessing yes, but I want to make sure the answer is digestible.

Comment: Hi @Giskard I'm coming more from an optimisation background, so the more straightforward the explanation the better! Thanks.

Comment: Also see this: https://x.com/amit_k_goyal/status/1717156615315427769?s=20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "[Dynamic economics An online textbook with dynamic graphics for the introduction to economics](https://www.online-vwl.de/english/micro/dynvwlengse29.html#x54-6300010.3)" by Prof. Dr. Christian Bauer:

> A function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},(x,y)\to f(x,y)$ is called homogeneous of the degree $n\in \mathbb{R}$, if for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ the following is valid:
> $$
> f(kx,ky) = k^n f(x,y) \ \forall k\in\mathbb{R}_0^+
> $$

A [lot of utility functions](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/40682/homogeneous-utilities-anything-other-than-ces) (all CES, including C-D) have this property. It is also well-known that for [functions with this property the demand for the goods is linear in income](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/8519/how-to-show-that-a-homothetic-utility-function-has-demand-functions-which-are-li), thus none will be 'more necessary' than another.

You could use something like quasilinear utility, which does not have this property:
$$
U(x,y) = v(x) + y
$$
where $v()$ is usually a concave function with an initially steep slope, e.g.; $\ln()$. In this case below a certain income level all income is spent on $x$, above the income level no income is spent on $x$. The amount consumed also depends on the price ratio. Whether such a simple function is useful for your model depends on what you are trying to achieve. This type of function is often used in IO literature, though personally I think its use is not always justified.

Comment: Thank you! What is "IO" literature? Also, would you be able to supplement your answer with a brief discussion of [Stone-Geary utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Geary_utility_function)? I would just like some intuition on how the quasilinear approach differs from CD with a subsistence level.

Comment: IO stands for Industrial Organization. I will defer to others on questions of Stone-Geary utility, I don't know enough about it :)